# What are the positive and negative forms of a command line option in Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, command-line

I am new to Linux. I am trying to compile and execute a c++ file. When I read the gcc manual, I found something in the manual that I don't understand:

> Many options have long names starting with -f or with -W---for
>   example, -fmove-loop-invariants, -Wformat and so on.  Most of these
>   have both **positive and negative forms**; the negative form of -ffoo is
>   -fno-foo.  This manual documents only one of these two forms, whichever one is not the default.

Can someone please explain what are the positive and negative forms of a command line option?

Comment: Well, I could not find a duplicate. Or maybe, "easily find". *＋1* for asking an original question.

Comment: Er, just like it says... `-ffoo` and `-fno-foo`. Note that this is a GCC-specific convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The positive form of the option enables some feature of the compiler, the negative form disables that feature.

For instance, `-fmove-loop-invariants` enables this optimization setting. To disable it, use `-fno-move-loop-invariants`.

Having both forms is useful so that you can override an option that might have been set using a default set of options in a build script or makefile. Also, some options enable or disable groups of settings at once, you can then use a later, more specific option to undo parts of this.

And sometimes you might use an option that's the same as the default, just to make your intentions explicit.

Comment: Also, because some flags can change groups of flags all at once. Like -Wunused-parameter is off by default, so the man page lists the positive form -Wunused-parameter, but if you put -Wall -Wextra, that's among the enabled warnings, so to turn off just that one warning again, you do -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter. Similarly, the -O* optimization flags affect lots of the -f flags.